# VSTO: which event cannot hooked to the object directly?

Tags: excel, events, vsto

For some event, the subscription by hooking the event directly object is failing but working when you use a local variable.
I haven't figured out why yet, who does?

I came across this mystery as I start working with `CommandBarsEvents.OnUpdate`, in order to [detect interaction with a shape](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/CSExcelNewEventForShapes-0e26b1f2), what can comes with certain problems as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12329896/commandbars-onupdate-stops-being-fired).
There are other events with that problem?

Answer (score 0):

to keep clear here comes an (incomplete) overview of events which are affected and which not

- events what **DO** need a local variable

  1. `this.Application.CommandBars.OnUpdate`
     .

  Their code has to be like this:

  ```
  using Office = Microsoft.Office.Core;
  namespace Project
  {
      public partial class AddIn
      {      
          private Office.CommandBars commandBars; //declaration of local variable

          private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
          {
              commandBars = this.Application.CommandBars; //initialization of local variable
              commandBars.OnUpdate += new Office._CommandBarsEvents_OnUpdateEventHandler(commandBars_OnUpdate); //"indirect" subscription to event`
          }

      }
  }
  ```
- events what **NOT** need a local variable

  1. `((InteropExcel.AppEvents_Event)Application).NewWorkbook`
  2. `this.Application.WorkbookNewSheet`
  3. `this.Application.WorkbookOpen`
     .

  Their code can be like this:

  ```
  using Office = Microsoft.Office.Core;
  namespace Project
  {
      public partial class AddIn
      {      
          private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
          {
               ((InteropExcel.AppEvents_Event)Application).NewWorkbook += new InteropExcel.AppEvents_NewWorkbookEventHandler(Excel_NewWorkbook_EventHandler); //"direct" subscription to event`
          }

      }
  }
  ```